# $regex requires regular expression error mongodb stitch

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I get this error when I try to query to Mongodb Stitch:

> Error: $regex requires regular expression
>       at client.js:557

Here is my code:

```
const searchByName = async (data) => {
    let db = await MongoConnect(),
      collection_users = db.collection('users'),
      users

console.log(data.name)

let regxName = new RegExp(data.name)

console.log(regxName)

try {
    let users = await collection_users.find({ name: { $regex: regxName, 
      $options: 'i' } }).execute()
    console.log(users)
} catch (error) {
    return error
}
```

Comment: Debug and figure out value of `regxName` populating.

Comment: What does `console.log(data.name)` produce?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, this method works. (All client side)

```js
import { BSON } from 'mongodb-stitch'

let bsonRegex = new BSON.BSONRegExp('pattern', 'i')

let users = await collection_users.find({ name: bsonRegex }).execute()
```

Returns results from pattern

Comment: Thanks! Regular RegExp didn't work in Stitch while it worked in console but BSON solved that issue.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB Stitch Functions you have to use [BSON.BSONRegExp](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/reference/functions/utilities/#bson) global function that will convert it to correct format for Stitch.

Here is an example :

```
exports = function(keyword) {
    var mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
    var coll = mongodb.db("DBNAME").collection("users");
    return coll.find({
      name: BSON.BSONRegExp(keyword, "i") 
    }).toArray();
};
```

and call it on client like :

```
stitchClientPromise.then(stitchClient => 
  stitchClient.executeFunction('FUNC_NAME', 'jhon')
).then(users => console.log('success: ', users))
  .catch(e => console.log('error: ', e));
```